# Problems fitting sheet to a single page in xlsx files using the Apache POI library

Tags: java, printing, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to create some xlsx files using the Apache POI library for Java and everything to create the files is working fine.

The problem comes when I want to print those files using a physical printer. I want to make each sheet in my workbooks fit to a single page. I looked around in the documentation and the following code would be supposed to work:

```
       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("format sheet");

       PrintSetup ps = sheet.getPrintSetup();

       sheet.setAutobreaks(true);

       ps.setFitHeight((short)1);
       ps.setFitWidth((short)1);

       for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            sheet.createRow(i);
            sheet.getRow(i).createCell(0).setCellValue("Test " + i);
        }

       FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test.xlsx");
       wb.write(output);
       output.close();
```

But it doesn't... When I try to print it, it prints to three sheets (what it would actually be supposed to print on if I didn't use the PrintSetup part). So the code just doesn't do anything at all.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with that code?

Also, I have another question about printing xlsx files: I want to know if there's a way to print the xlsx files from my Java program without actually opening the files and clicking on print? Like *wb.printAllSheetsInWorkbook();* or something like that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After

```
ps.setFitHeight((short)1);
ps.setFitWidth((short)1);
```

Use

```
sheet.setFitToPage(true);
```

Comment: I found this while loking for a similar problem but using NPOI (.NET Port of POI) and I followed the equivalent actions you mentioned with the slightest variation; I set FitHeight=0 so that Excel will do "Fit all Columns in One Page". Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Adding sheet.setAutobreaks(true); before sheet.setFitToPage(true); worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work with poi-3.8 and office 2013 working with xls format

if i create the sheet from poi, the settings don't work.
if i open/create the sheet in office excel, and set the page height from office excel (say, to 2 pages), and save, and then run the program to read this sheet and set the height/width (say, to 1 page), then it works.

seems like the record doesn't get written if we generate the sheet from poi.
if the record already exists, then poi is able to update it.

Another weird thing - generate xls from poi - 6kb. open the excel in office and save - 22 kb. open the excel in office, adjust height/width and save - 30 kb.
definitely poi isn't writing out the record when it generates the file. probably other info is also missing (22 )

Comment: Ha! why is it that you research for an answer for days and then when you post a question, you get to the answer by yourself in seconds!  **sheet.setAutobreaks(true);** is needed for the setting to work.